# What should be the Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a String like "ANCBTH2016100931011730300000458" which always start with ANCBTH followed by Numbers.

What can be a regex to match a word which may or may not have spaces and the position of space is also not fixed.

Example:

```
ANCBTH2016100931011730300000458
ANCBTH 2016100931011730300000458
ANCBTH 20161009 31011730300000458
```

I would like to have a regex which satisfied all above examples.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve that so far?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, that would not meet the criteria of `followed by numbers`

Comment: Noted, @table. And, it seems that OP would like to allow whitespaces(space) too alongside numbers for the correct execution based on his last paragraph!

Answer (score 2):

You can test this regex: `ANCBTH((?:\s?\d+)*)`

To test: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HsL0sS/1)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove all the spaces from incoming string e.g.

```
String yourString = "ANCBTH 20161009 31011730300000458";

yourString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

yourString will become like ANCBTH2016100931011730300000458

and then you may run a regex like

```
ANCBTH[0-9]*
```

and all of your string with spaces anywhere will pass this pattern.